# Matching Algorithm of Objects stored in Dictionaries

Tags: swift

I have data in a ViewController available like this:

```
1x [Group] contains
N [User] have
N [Pets] (Dog, Rat, Cat and so on. Each User has similar or different pets)
```

I want to find out which common Pet has the Group.

What my code currently does:

Create a List of ALL Pets. Then get a list of all Unique Pets in the group. For this unique Pet, count the occurrence of every Item of the Unique in the ALL List. If the count is like the count of Users, I have a Match.

This code feels not right / and or stupid to me.

Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, I would get the pets of each user as a Set and then take the *intersection* of all those sets. The result will be just those pets present in *every* user's list of pets.

You didn't show any code, so I'll make some up. Here are the types:

```
struct Group {
    let users : [User]
}
struct User {
    let pets : [PetType]
}
enum PetType {
    case dog
    case cat
    case mouse
    case rat
}
```

And here is some initial data:

```
let user1 = User(pets:[.dog, .cat, .rat])
let user2 = User(pets:[.cat])
let user3 = User(pets:[.rat, .cat])
let group = Group(users:[user1,user2,user3])
// only `.cat` is common to the whole group
```

Now let's see if I can discover that only `.cat` is common to the whole group...

```
let petsets = group.users.map {$0.pets}.map {Set.init($0)}
if var result = petsets.first {
    petsets.dropFirst().forEach { result = result.intersection($0) }
    print(result) // .cat
}
```

That's extremely efficient because set arithmetic is efficient.

Comment: Thank you for your time Matt. Will look into it